# Looking for a Science Fiction Omnibus

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the name of a science fiction omnibus that I read between 1985 - 1989. I remember two short stories in this omnibus, one was about aliens that visited Earth and a man was trying to trade paint for some of their technology.

Another was of a machine intelligence that time travelled to the past and met itself in its earlier form. I'd like either the name of either the omnibus in question *or* the names of these two short stories.

Comment: I read the first one in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Science_Fiction_Hall_of_Fame,_Volume_Two which I still have *somewhere* in my house, I'm sure.

Answer (score 16):

The second story sounds like the novelette ["Fulfillment"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63009) by [A. E. van Vogt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt):

> The truth has already been verified by my integrating interoceptors. The Brain and I are one—but thousands of years apart. If the Brain is destroyed in the twentieth century, then I will not exist in the thirtieth. Or will I?

The other short story sounds familiar, but I can't place it.

The [ISFDB page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63009) for "Fulfillment" lists all the anthologies and collections it has appeared in. Maybe you will recognize the one you're looking for by the cover or the contents.

Answer (score 12):

First story is almost certainly Clifford Simak's "The Big Front Yard" -- the trading of ideas (with the protagonist offering paint) is a key identifier. A story summary at:

http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2008/06/clifford-d-simak-big-front-yard.html

includes this and other details to demonstrate the match.

I also agree with the ID of the second story. I'm not sure there's a single collection that includes both.

Comment: There definitely isn't any overlap on their isfdb.org pages.

Comment: @Bobson I agree. It'll either end up being some grotty little reprint or just that he read them back to back in separate books.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187000/looking-for-a-short-story-title-about-a-weird-house for an answered question with additional details